# Speeding up jQuery mobile - page caching and removing HTML from content not in view

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-mobile

I am trying to speed up my jQuery mobile web app, and upon a Google I found out about page caching. Can't seem to find a proper detailer explanation as to what it does, so can anyone shed light as to why exactly it is bad? As many people seem to be wanting it turned off.

My main question is (I think) related to this - basically I have many js functions that insert quite a lot of HTML into different pages upon app start and then when each page loads. For example when I load my slideshow page, it loads the slideshow in pageload so it is not in the DOM all the time. Is this what one should be doing for ALL pages? Does too much HTML make a very large difference to the general app speed?

I was thinking of hiding all of the content of each of my 8 pages, but using js to display the content on each page load, but is this worth it? (and then obviously hiding it again on pagehide.)

I assume this is somehow related to page caching?

Also, I am using the multi-page template so all pages are in one HTML file, but in a case where I have quite a lot of external js libraries, would it make more sense to have this page load in another HTML file as not to slow down the rest of the app with HTML and canvas tags/js file includes???

Thanks

Comment: Only pages that are AJAX-loaded through other URLs are cached in jQuery Mobile. All pages in multipage documents always remain present in the DOM regardless of the cache settings, so I do not think disabling page caching will help you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to understand page cashing you need to understand how jQuery Mobile handles page loading.

### 1 HTML / multiple pages

This solution is probably easiest to handle. Everything is in one big file, you wont have too many problems if you keep everything organized. But, if you are creating a large web app (specially if this web app is going to become a mobile app through the phonegap framework for example) this solution is going to create lots of problems.

Because this is one large file jQuery Mobile will load everything to the DOM. This will cause faster transitions effects while at the same time making your web app bloated.

In case you are creating web app meant only for desktop browsers the this is the solution for you. In any other case run from it.

### Multiple HTML template

This template is better suited for mobile devices. Only one HTML page will be loaded into the DOM, and every previous page will be removed from it (unless specially defined). This solution can have problems with page transitions, but its not going to be a problem unless you are creating large HTML files.

Only pages loaded with ajax will be loaded into the DOM. So every new HTML file will be loaded and every old/previous file will be removed.

### Page caching

If you are using **Multiple HTML template** solution you can prefetch some pages, thus preventing transition problems.

Pages can be prefetched with load page function:

```
$.mobile.loadPage( pageUrl, { showLoadMsg: false } );
```

or by putting a **data-dom-cache="true"** attribute inside a page div container, like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="cacheMe" data-dom-cache="true">
```

### Auto page caching

Caching can be also turned on/off on a mobile level with this property:

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
```

or disabled like this:

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = false;
```

This property must be loaded inside a mobileinit event:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
});
```

This property cant be used with a **1 HTML / multiple pages template**.

More about this can be found in the official documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/pages/page-cache.html