# JQuery Mobile - Implement site without dom caching

Tags: jquery-mobile

Am doing the following when using JQM. Please let me know the impact.

1. Am not using dom caching when using JQM. Have completely removed dom caching for the site.
2. Am loading some links without AJAX.
3. How can we specify the page expiry in JQM, if we have to implement it.
   If we disable AJAX based of loading in JQM by using $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false, what will be the impact. If we disable AJAX completely, then we can specify the page expiry. Is it not?

Please provide your valuable inputs so that it will help others who are looking out for the same topic.

Comment: Is everyone busy? Nobody seems to be answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impacts:

`Caching pages` keep previously-visited pages in the `DOM` instead of
   removing them,  so that they are available instantly if the user
   returns to them.
         To remove caching, you could do,

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
   $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = false;    
});
```

If you are not caching page, previous page will not be instantly available.

The drawback of `DOM` `caching` is that the `DOM` can get very large, 
resulting in `slowdowns` and `memory issues` on some devices

[Refer link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349126/speeding-up-jquery-mobile-page-caching-and-removing-html-from-content-not-in-v),
[Refer link2](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html)

`data-ajax="false"` will be loaded with full refreshment of the page, with `no animated transition`

[Refer link3](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)

For setting expiration of page [Refer link4](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/new-attribute-dom-cache-expires-120)

If you disable `ajax` completely, there will not be a smooth animated transition to your next page

Comment: is it not possible to set the page expiry in html,using meta tag "<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" 
CONTENT="Mon, 22 Jul 2002 11:12:01 GMT">" instead of having them in the DOM.

Comment: The Meta Expires tag defines the expiration date and time of the web document that is being indexed. It has been said that the Meta Expires tag is helpful for those periods when your business is running a limited time event/offer or if there is a preset date when your web document will no longer be valid for indexing. Once you have reached the listed date, the search engines are then supposed to delete your web page from their database.

Comment: Ok then is the page not getting cached by browsers if you do not use JQuery Mobile.